# IDENTITY_INSERT ON not working - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, identity, identity-column

I am having problems with my query.
Basically, what I am trying to do is empty out a table and copy the records from the same table in another database.

I did use the `SET  IDENTITY_INSERT` code to make sure that the identity column is turned off before I perform my insert. But somehow, it still throws me the error message:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.UI_PAGE' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Below is my query:

```
DELETE FROM [DB1].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DB1].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] ON

INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[MY_TABLE]
   SELECT *
   FROM  [DB2].[dbo].[MY_TABLE]

SET  IDENTITY_INSERT [DB1].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] OFF
```

Can someone point me as to which step I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify all the column names when inserting with IDENTITY INSERT ON when using INSERT INTO

```
INSERT INTO  [DB1].[dbo].[MY_TABLE](TabelID,Field1,Field2,Field3...)
SELECT * FROM  [DB2].[dbo].[MY_TABLE]
```

In case you did not know there is a nifty little trick in ssms. If select a table and expand its' nodes you ctrl-c copy on the Columns node and that will place a comma-delimited list of the field names on your clipboards text buffer.

Comment: And I would even recommend to **always** explicitly list the columns in your all of your `INSERT` AND `SELECT` statements. It's a bit more typing up front, but it makes for a lot of avoided, hard to find issues and errors!

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the first answer given by Ross Bush,
If your table has many columns then to get those columns name by using this command.

```
SELECT column_name + ','
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = 'TableName'
for xml path('')
```

(after removing the last comma(',')) Just copy past columns name.